# Integral $\int_0^2 \frac{\arctan x}{x^2+2x+2}dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I am tring to evaluate

$$I=\int_0^2 \frac{\arctan x}{x^2+2x+2}dx$$

The first thing I did was to notice that

$$\frac{1}{x^2+2x+2}=\frac{1}{(x+1)^2+1}=\frac{d}{dx}\arctan(x+1)$$

So I integrated by parts in order to get

$$I=\arctan 2\arctan 3-\int_0^2\frac{\arctan(x+1)}{1+x^2}dx$$

I let $x=u+1$ but when I do that I get

$$I=\arctan 2\arctan 3+\int_{-1}^1\frac{\arctan(u)}{1+(1+u)^2}du
   =\arctan 2\arctan 3$$

Now this is not close to the approximation given by wolfram. What have I done wrong and how to solve this?[image]

Comment: Why would the last integral be zero? The integrand is not odd.

Comment: oh.. you are right. On hurry I saw  it as $\int_{-1}^1\frac{\arctan(u)}{1+(1+u^2)}du$

Comment: There is another mistake, in the change of variable $x=u+1$ (then $\arctan(x+1)$ would become $\arctan(u+2)$).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**An elementary solution.** Let $I$ denote the integral. Apply the substitution $x=\frac{2t}{t+\sqrt{5}}$ to obtain

$$ I = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\arctan\left(\frac{2t}{t+\sqrt{5}}\right)}{\sqrt{5}+4t+\sqrt{5}t^2} \, dt. \tag{1} $$

Substituting $t \mapsto 1/t$, we find that

$$ I = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\arctan\left(\frac{2}{1+\sqrt{5} t}\right)}{\sqrt{5}+4t+\sqrt{5}t^2} \, dt. \tag{2} $$

But it is easy to check that

$$ \arctan\left(\frac{2t}{t+\sqrt{5}}\right) + \arctan\left(\frac{2}{1+\sqrt{5} t}\right) = \arctan(2) $$

holds, either by utilizing the addition formula for arctan or by differentiating the LHS to check that the LHS is constant and then plugging $t=0$ to determine the value of the constant.

Therefore by averaging $(1)$ and $(2)$, we obtain

$$ I
= \frac{\arctan(2)}{2} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dt}{\sqrt{5}+4t+\sqrt{5}t^2}
= \frac{\arctan(2)\arctan(1/2)}{2}. $$

Comment: Thank you! But could you explain what is the intuition behind the substitution?

Comment: @Sonkun, Not easy to explain, as it is half intuition and half some abstract theory. But let me try anyway. If $p(z)$ is a quadratic polynomial and $z=\gamma(w)=\frac{aw+b}{cw+d}$ is a [*Möbius transformation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation), then it is easy to check that $$\frac{dz}{p(z)}=\frac{dw}{q(w)}$$ for another quadratic polynomial. In our case, we have extra factor $\arctan(x)$, but it is also an integral of reciprocal of a quadratic polynomial. All these observations lead us to believe that Möbius transformations are good candidates to try.

Comment: @Sonkun, Now, if we believe that the problem can be solved by means of symmetry, we may try an arbitrary Möbius transformation $\gamma$ which maps $0$ to $2$ and vice versa. Solving the equation $\gamma(0)=2$ and $\gamma(2)=0$, we find that any such $\gamma$ is given by the form $$z=\gamma(w)=\frac{2-w}{1-cw},$$ and choosing $c=-2$ shows $$ \frac{dz}{z^2+2z+2}=-\frac{dw}{w^2+2w+2}. $$ Of course this does not necessarily mean that the arctangent part can be resolved, but the problem is cooked up so that $\arctan(z)+\arctan(\gamma(z))$ is constant. So we are done!

Comment: @SangchulLee Where did you get the idea to use an arbitrary Mobius transformation $\gamma$ to map $0$ to $2$ and vice versa? Is it just because they are the limits to the integral? And how did you choose the $c$ value? I don't see where you get $-2$ from. And lastly, your substitution is$$\gamma(w)=\frac {2-w}{1+w}$$which is different than the substitution you used in the answer. How did you come up with your substitution? Sorry if this seems trivial, I'm completely new to Mobius transformations and really curious as to how they work and what they are.

Comment: @FrankW. As we want to exploit the symmetry, one has to create a sort of complementary version of the original integral $\int_{0}^{2}\frac{\arctan x}{x^2+2x+2}\,dx$ so that they sum up to a simpler expression. So it is natural to find a substitution that preserves the domain of integration. When doing so, one may choose to preserve the orientation (so that $0\to0$ and $2\to2$) or to reverse the orientation (so that $0\leftrightarrow2$). And as for the $\gamma$ above, it works for the original integral directly, not for the modified version in $\text{(1)}$.

Answer (score 7):

I agree with Sangchul Lee. By writing $\arctan(x)$ as $\text{Im}\,\log(1+ix)$ and by using partial fraction decomposition and integration by parts one gets

$$ \int_{0}^{2}\frac{\arctan(x)}{x^2+2x+2}\,dx = -\frac{\pi^2}{48}+\frac{1}{2}\arctan(2)\arctan\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-\frac{\log^2(5)}{8}+\frac{1}{2}\text{Re}\left[\text{Li}_2(i-2)+\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{i+2}{5}\right)\right].$$
On the other hand, by the [functional relations](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Dilogarithm.html) for $\text{Li}_2$ the above line simplifies into
$$ \frac{1}{2}\arctan(2)\arctan\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) $$
which is the only reasonable option, since the given integral is clearly pretty close to one fourth.

Comment: could you check the photo that I added? Is the exercise wrong?

Comment: @Sonkun: answer updated.

Comment: You actually managed to do that painstaking computation! I just threw the partial fraction decomposition into Mathematica and brushed up the output a little bit, so it is glad the final answer is very nice.

Comment: but this is college admission problem.. Is there a simpler solution? I don't know so much about dilogarithm.

Comment: @Sonkun: as stated, the value of the integral is pretty obviously an element of $(0,1)$, and a single option fits in this range.

Comment: And with a bit of reverse-engineering, you may just differentiate $\arctan(x+1)\left[\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan(x+1)\right]$.

Comment: I see, thank you! Pretty ugly exercise then.

Answer (score 5):

**There is no need to evaluate the integral to answer the original question.** 
 The original question is a multiple choice question so ruling out every option but the right one leads to the right answer of course. One sees that the integrand is positive almost everywhere. Moreover  the arctangent function is increasing, so one has:
\begin{align}
0 < \int^2_ 0 \frac{\arctan(x)}{x^2+2x+2}\,dx &\leq \arctan(2) \int^2 _0 \frac{1}{x^2+2x+2}\,dx\\&= \arctan(2)\left( \arctan(3)-\arctan(1)\right)
\end{align}
By the addition formula for arctangent function one sees that:
\begin{align}
\arctan(3)-\arctan(1) = \arctan\left( \frac 1 2 \right)
\end{align}
Now define for $x>0$ the function:
$$f(x): = \arctan(x)\arctan\left( \frac 1 x\right)$$ 
This function is strictly positive. Moreover it tends to zero as $x\to 0^+$ and as $x\to\infty$ and it is  differentiable with only one stationary point $x=1$ (check this!) which clearly corresponds with the maximum. So:
\begin{align*}
f(x) \leq f(1) = \arctan(1)^2 = \frac{\pi^2}{4^2} <  \frac{4^2}{4^2}=1
\end{align*}
Hence:
\begin{align}
0 < \int^2_ 0 \frac{\arctan(x)}{x^2+2x+2}\,dx < 1 < \pi < 2\pi
\end{align}
So what is the only option that can be the right answer?