# How to find $\int_0^2\frac{\arctan x}{x^2+2x+2}\,dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Find $$\int_0^2\frac{\arctan x}{x^2+2x+2}\,dx$$

Any hints on how to approach this problem in the first place? The answer should be: $$\frac{1}{2}\arctan(2)\arctan\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$$

I tried parts, and using $x=\frac1t$, but to no use. I also tried using an integral calculator, but it uses complex analysis, which I haven't learned yet.

Comment: Use the search option. This has been posted here many times.

Comment: @Zacky Thank you a lot!! But have you got any idea on how to "answer" it so that is duped https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2799064/use-of-substitution-into-the-integral-int-02-frac-arctan-xx22x2dx